Analyzing the asymptotic behavior of a given function $f(\mu, t)$ as $t \to \infty$
Consider the following improper integral
$$
f(\mu, t) = \frac{2}{\pi} 
\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin u}{u} 
\frac{\left(U+u\right) \exp\left(-\frac{\mu}{t} \, u\right) - 2U \exp\left(-\frac{\mu}{t} \, U \right)}{U-u} \, \mathrm{d} u \, , 
$$
where $U = (u^2 + t^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ with $\mu, t \ge 0$.
Here, I am interested in the asymptotic behavior of this integral as $t \to \infty$.
By taking the limit $t\to\infty$, it can easily be shown that
$$
\lim_{t \to \infty} f(\mu, t) = 1 - 2\exp(-\mu) \, .
$$
However, I would like to understand how the function approaches this limit. Any insights or assistance would be greatly appreciated.
It is important to note that expanding the function in a series around $t \to \infty$ and then integrating with respect to $u$ results in an undefined integral.
Specifically, the integrand can be expanded around $t=\infty$ as
$$
\frac{2}{\pi} \, \sin u\left( \frac{1-2e^{-\mu}}{u} + \frac{\mu}{t} \left( 
2-\mu-2e^{-\mu} \right) \right) + \mathcal{O}(t^{-2}) \, .
$$
Thanks!

I considered your second asymptotics in a separate post. I don't know whether it is relevant to your investigation, but the problem was interesting by itself, and improved my knowledge of the asymptotic of non-analytical functions )

$$I(\mu, t)=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin u}u\frac{(u+\sqrt{u^2+t^2})e^{-\frac{\mu u}t}-2\sqrt{t^2+u^2}e^{-\frac\mu t\sqrt{t^2+u^2}}}{\sqrt{u^2+t^2}-u}du$$
$$\overset{u=xt}{=}\Im\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{ixt}}x\frac{(\sqrt{1+x^2}+x)e^{-\mu x}-2\sqrt{1+x^2}e^{-\mu\sqrt{1+x^2}}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}-x}dx$$
Now we switch to complex plane and integrate along a quarter-circle of the radius $R\to\infty$ (counter-clockwise). We also add a small quarter-circle of the radius $r\to0$ - to go around $z=0$ (clockwise). As we do not have singularities inside the contour,
$$I(\mu,t)=\Im\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-xt}}x\frac{(\sqrt{1-x^2}+ix)e^{-\mu i x}-2\sqrt{1-x^2}e^{-\mu\sqrt{1-x^2}}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}+ix}dx-\Im I_{C_R}-\Im I_{C_r}\tag{0}$$
Strictly speaking, we have the branch point on the imaginary axis ($z=i$), but integration around this point gives an exponentially small term $\sim e^{-t}$
Integration around $z=0$ gives
$$\Im I_{C_r}=\Im\int_{\pi/2}^0\frac{e^{-rte^{i\phi}}}{re^{i\phi}}\frac{(\sqrt{1+r^2e^{2i\phi}}+re^{i\phi})e^{-\mu re^{i\phi}}-2\sqrt{1+r^2e^{2i\phi}}e^{-\mu\sqrt{1+r^2e^{2i\phi}}}}{\sqrt{1+r^2e^{2i\phi}}-re^{i\phi}}ire^{i\phi}d\phi$$
$$\to -\frac\pi2\big(1-2e^{-\mu}\big)\,\,\text{at}\,\,r\to0\tag{1}$$
Integrating by parts
$$\Im I_{C_R}=\Im\int_R^{iR}\frac{e^{itz}}z\frac{(\sqrt{1+z^2}+x)e^{-\mu z}-2\sqrt{1+z^2}e^{-\mu\sqrt{1+z^2}}}{\sqrt{1+z^2}-z}dz$$
$$=\Im\frac{e^{itz}}{itz}\frac{(\sqrt{1+z^2}+x)e^{-\mu z}-2\sqrt{1+z^2}e^{-\mu\sqrt{1+z^2}}}{\sqrt{1+z^2}-z}\,\bigg|_{R}^{iR}+\text{integral of derivative}$$
But for $\mu>0$ we get exponentially small values on both limits. Continuing the process of integration by parts, we see that all the terms of this integral are exponentially small ($\sim\max(e^{-\mu R},e^{-R})$)
$$I_{C_R}\to0\,\,\text{at}\,\,R\to 0\tag{2}$$
Evaluating the first term in (0), we drop all the story with branch points (it gives $\sim e^{-t}$ terms), and decompose the integrand near $z=0$. Integration term by term is straightforward and gives
$$\Im\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-xt}}x\frac{(\sqrt{1-x^2}+ix)e^{-\mu i x}-2\sqrt{1-x^2}e^{-\mu\sqrt{1-x^2}}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}+ix}dx$$
$$=\frac{2-\mu-2e^{-\mu}}t\left(1-\frac{1-\mu}t\right)+O\Big(\frac1{t^3}\Big)\tag{3}$$
Putting (1), (2) and (3) in (0)
$$\boxed{\,\,I(\mu, t)=\frac\pi2\big(1-2e^{-\mu}\big)+\frac{2-\mu-2e^{-\mu}}t\left(1-\frac{1-\mu}t\right)+O\Big(\frac1{t^3}\Big)\,\,}$$
Numeric check (WA) confirms the answer. We also see that $I(\mu=0,t)=-\frac \pi2+O\Big(\frac1{t^3}\Big)\to-\frac\pi2$, as it should be.

It looks like the term $1/t^2$ is wrong because $I(\mu,t)$ is not defined for $\alpha=0$, something it should in principle.

Actually, $t = \alpha x$ and $\mu = \alpha h$ so I am interested in the limit as $\alpha \to 0$. It looks like the terms with $1/x^2$ is undefined in the limit $\alpha \to 0$ (division by zero.)

This another situation, when $\frac\mu t=const$ and $t\to 0$. The found asymptotic is applicable at  $t\to\infty$

A heuristic approach gives for $\frac\mu t=h=const,,$ and $,t\to0$
$$I(h,t)=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin u}u\frac{(\sqrt{u^2+t^2}+u)e^{-hu}-2\sqrt{u^2+t^2}e^{-h\sqrt{u^2+t^2}}}{\sqrt{u^2+t^2}-u}du$$
$$=\arctan h-\frac\pi2+\frac{2h}{h^2+1}+O(\sqrt t)=\frac{2h}{h^2+1}-\arctan\frac1h+O(\sqrt t)$$

Numeric shows that the second term is rather $O(t)$

Too long for a comment
Though this is not related to the OP post, the question was mentioned in the comment, and is worth investigation by itself (being an interesting problem).
For $\frac\mu t=h\,(=const)\,$ to find the asymptotics of
$$I(h,t)=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin u}u\frac{(\sqrt{u^2+t^2}+u)e^{-hu}-2\sqrt{u^2+t^2}e^{-h\sqrt{u^2+t^2}}}{\sqrt{u^2+t^2}-u}du\,\,\text{at}\,\,t\to0$$
The zero terms $\,\,I(h,t=0)=\frac{2h}{h^2+1}-\frac\pi2+\arctan h+o(1)\,\,$ can be found rather easily, but the next one is not quite easy to evaluate; my initial suppositions about $\,o(1)\,$ was wrong. The problem is not simple mainly because of the fact that $\,I(h,t)\,$ is not analytical near $\,t=0\,$, and we cannot use straightforward decompositions to catch the flavour of the next terms.
One of the systematic approaches is the following. We split the interval of integration on $[0;\sqrt t];\,\,[\sqrt t;\infty)$ and decompose the integrand on every interval. Namely, on the first interval
$$\frac{\sin u} u=1-\frac{u^2}6+...;\,\,e^{-h\sqrt{u^2+t^2}}=1-h\sqrt{u^2+t^2}+...$$
On the second interval $\,t\ll u$, and we are allowed to decompose
$$\sqrt{u^2+t^2}=u\sqrt{1+\frac{t^2}{u^2}}=u+\frac{t^2}{2u}-...$$
Rearranging the integrand a bit and applying decomposition we get a bunch of doable integrals. But the difficulty is that we get lots of terms $\big(\sqrt t,\, t,\,t^{3/2},\,...\big)$. I spent one night and wrote a ton of paper to understand that it makes sense to invest time into seeking for a better approach.
I guess I found the one, and though it is heurustic, it allows to find as many terms of the asymptotic as we want.
We can present the initial integral in the form
$$I(h,t)=-\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin u}u e^{-hu}du+2\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin u}u \left(e^{-hu}-e^{-h\sqrt{u^2+t^2}}\right)du$$
$$+\,2\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin u}{\sqrt{u^2+t^2}-u}\left(e^{-hu}-e^{-h\sqrt{u^2+t^2}}\right)du=\left(\arctan h-\frac\pi2\right)+2I_2+2I_3\tag{1}$$
where
$$I_2=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin u}u \left(e^{-hu}-e^{-h\sqrt{u^2+t^2}}\right)du=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin u}u e^{-hu}\left(1-e^{-h(\sqrt{u^2+t^2}-u)}\right)du$$
$$=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin u}u e^{-hu}\left(1-e^{-h\frac{t^2}{\sqrt{u^2+t^2}+u}}\right)du$$
We notice that $\,\frac{t^2}{\sqrt{u^2+t^2}+u}\ll1\,$ on the whole interval, so we can apply the decomposition with respect to this factor.
$$I_2=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin u}u e^{-hu}\left(\frac{ht^2}{\sqrt{u^2+t^2}+u}-\frac{h^2t^4}{2(\sqrt{u^2+t^2}+u)^2}\right)+...$$
The second term in this integral gives only $\,O(t^3)\,$ contribution. Indeed,
$$\frac{h^2t^4}2\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin u}u\frac{e^{-hu}}{(\sqrt{u^2+t^2}+u)^2}du\overset{u=xt}{=}\frac{h^2t^3}2\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(xt)}{xt}\frac{e^{-hxt}}{(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x)^2}dx$$
But the absolute value of the integrand is majorized by the integrable function $\frac1{(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x)^2}$. By the dominated convergence theorem we are allowed to lead $t\to 0$ under the integral sign and get
$$\to \frac{h^2t^3}2\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x)^2}\overset{x=\sinh s}{=}\frac{h^2t^3}4\int_0^\infty(e^{-s}+e^{-3s})ds=\frac{h^2t^3}3$$
It is straightforward to see that next terms in $I_2$ will bring higher powers of $t$. As we want now to evaluate the terms including only $\sim t^2$, we drop them.
Integrating by parts the first term in $\,I_2$
$$I_2=ht^2\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin u\,e^{-hu}}u\frac{du}{\sqrt{u^2+t^2}+u}+O(t^3)$$
$$=ht^2\left(\frac12\,\operatorname{arcsinh}\Big(\frac u t\Big)-\frac14e^{-2\operatorname{arcsinh}\big(\frac u t\big)}\right)\frac{\sin u}ue^{-hu}\,\bigg|_{u=0}^\infty$$
$$-\frac{ht^2}2\int_0^\infty\left(\ln(u+\sqrt{u^2+t^2})-\ln t-\frac12\frac{t^2}{(\sqrt{u^2+t^2}+u)^2}\right)\left(\frac{\sin u}ue^{-hu}\right)'_udu+O(t^3)$$
The third term in the integral gives $O(t^4)$; in the first term the integral converges at $t=0$. It means that we are left with
$$=\frac{ht^2}4-\frac{ht^2}2(\ln2-\ln t)\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{\sin u}ue^{-hu}\right)'_udu-\frac{ht^2}2\int_0^\infty\ln u\left(\frac{\sin u}ue^{-hu}\right)'_udu+o(t^2)$$
$$I_2=\frac{ht^2}4+\frac{ht^2}2(\ln2-\ln t)-\frac{ht^2}2\int_0^\infty\ln u\left(\frac{\sin u}ue^{-hu}\right)'_udu+o(t^2)$$
To evaluate the last integral we can use analytical continuation and evaluate
$$J(s)=\int_0^\infty u^s\left(\frac{\sin u}ue^{-hu}\right)'_udu=\sin\left((s-1)\arctan\frac1h\right)(h^2+1)^\frac{1-s}2\frac{\Gamma(1+s)}{1-s}$$
Differentiating with respect to $s$, putting $s=0$, after some rearrangements we get
$$I_2=\frac{ht^2}4+\frac{ht^2}2(\ln2-\ln t)+\frac{ht^2}2\left(1-\gamma-\frac12\ln(1+h^2)-h\arctan\left(\frac1h\right)\right)+o(t^2)\tag{2}$$
In the same way we evaluate $I_3$, where we have to keep also the second term of the integrand decomposition:
$$I_3=\frac{h}{h^2+1}-\frac{h^2t^2}4\arctan\left(\frac1h\right)+o(t^2)\tag{3}$$
Putting (2) and (3) into (1)
$$\boxed{I(h,t)=\frac{2h}{1+h^2}-\arctan\Big(\frac1h\Big)+ht^2\left(\ln \frac1t+\frac32-\gamma+\ln2-\frac{3h}2\arctan\Big(\frac1h\Big)-\frac{\ln(1+h^2)}2\right)+o(t^2)}$$
WA numeric check confirms the result.
We see that at $h=0$ we get $\,-\frac\pi2$, as expected, but at $h\to\infty$ only two first terms behave in a right way and tend to zero, while the next ones tend to $\infty$. The answer is that we imposed the condition $h=const$, what means $ht\to0$ at $t\to0$ - we implicitly used the condition $ht\ll1$ in our evaluation.

Given the expansion at $t=\infty$ (which I didn't derive, but taking what's provided),
$$
\begin{align}
I &= \lim\limits_{t \to \infty} \int\limits_{u=0}^{\infty} \left\{\frac{2}{\pi} \sin(u) \left ( \frac{1-2e^{-\mu}}{u} + \frac{\mu}{t} (2 - \mu -2e^{-\mu}) \right) + \text{higher order terms} \right\} du\\
& = \lim\limits_{t \to \infty} \left\{\frac{2}{\pi} (1-2e^{-\mu}))\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(u)}{u} du + K \frac{\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\sin(u) du}{t}\right\}\\
&= 1- 2e^{-\mu} + \lim\limits_{t \to \infty}\frac{\text{result in [-1,1]}}{t} \\
&= 1- 2e^{-\mu}
\end{align}
$$

But this has already been shown by the OP. Furthermore, what is $\int_0^\infty \sin(u),\mathrm{d}u$?

OP derived the integral first and then took the limit. The question was why taking the limit and then integrating doesn't give the save answer. So I showed what happens if you take the limit first and then integrate. As for your question, I am claiming that it is an unknown but bound result between $[-1,1]$

Indeed, it is a question of how one interprets "I would like to understand how the function approaches this limit". To me, it seems the OP would like to know the error term to see how fast the limit is approached. Your answer for my question is not so satisfactory: $\int_0^\infty \sin(u),\mathrm{d}u$ is a divergent improper integral.
